# All elements from html not being extracted by Requests and BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape odds from a site that displays current odds from different agencies for an assignment on the effects of market competition. I am using Requests and BeautifulSoup to extract the relevant data. However after using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bestodds.com.au/odds/cricket/ICC-World-Twenty20/Sri-Lanka-v-Afghanistan_71992/"

r=requests.get(url)
Print(r.text)
```

It does not print any odds, yet if I inspect the element on the page I can see them in the html. How do I get Requests to import them into Python to extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` is not quite suitable to use in this case - the site is *quite dynamic* and uses multiple XHR requests and javascript to form the page. A quicker and much less painful way to get to the desired information would be to *use a real browser* automated via [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Here is an example code to get you started - headless [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org) browser is used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.bestodds.com.au/odds/cricket/ICC-World-Twenty20/Sri-Lanka-v-Afghanistan_71992/")

# waiting for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".odds-comparison")))

for comparison in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".odds-comparison"):
    description = comparison.find_element_by_css_selector(".description").text
    print(description)

driver.close()
```

It prints all the odds table descriptions on the page:

```
MATCH ODDS
MOST SIXES
TOP SRI LANKA BATSMAN
TOP AFGHANISTAN BATSMAN
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However when I "print(description)" the output is blank. As in after I press enter on the line the following line just comes up as "...". does it output the table into another file or should it display in the terminal?

Comment: @David it works for me - displaying the descriptions on a terminal. Have you changed anything in this code or are you executing it as is?

Comment: apologies it does work and have been able to print multiple elements from the .odds-comparison table e.g. ".oc-link--sportsbet.ppodds.quickbet-popover" or ".competitor-info" but it only prints the first row in each table?

Comment: @David I've just explained the problem and provided an example data extraction code. From what I see, I've answered the question you've initially asked. If you experience follow-up difficulties, consider creating a separate question here on SO. Make sure to provide all the necessary details. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It better to use urlopen :

```
   import urllib
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   from urllib.request import urlopen

   url = "https://www.bestodds.com.au/odds/cricket/ICC-World-Twenty20/Sri-Lanka-v-Afghanistan_71992/"

   response = urlopen(url)
   htmltext = BeautifulSoup(response)
   print (htmltext)
```

after that you can find what ever you want :

```
   Liste_page =htmltext.find('div',{"id":"pager"}).text
   Tr=htmltext.find('table',{"class":"additional_data"}).findNext('tbody').text
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am getting the same problem as I do when I execute the code that alecxe suggested. When I "print (htmltext)" or even "print (htmltext.text)" it does't display anything. I simply skips a line and then displays the usual ">>>". Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The data is most likely **loaded dynamically**.

It is not in the HTML.

You can try to understand which requests are used to retrieve the real data, or try using e.g. selenium webdriver to simulate a real browser (this second option will be much slower).

Beware that you **most likely violate the terms of usage** of that site. This can easily get you into trouble. They may also try to deliberately serve you bad data.